# CentOS install mod_dav_svn

Tags: svn, installation, dependencies, centos

I am trying to install subversion on a centos 5 VPS.
I managed to install subversion but when I try to do `yum install mod_dav_svn` I get this error:

> Error: Missing Dependency: httpd-mmn =
>   20051115 is needed by package
>   mod_dav_svn

After a lot of googling I read that you need Apache 2.2 (I previously had 2.0) so I recompiled the server with Apache 2.2 but I still got the same error.
I want to mention that I recompiled it with the mod_dav extension.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: how can I test if the mod_davn_svn is installed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

httpd-mmn usually comes with apache package for every version >= 2.0
the problem was that http* was in yum exclude list and it made yum think it wasn't installed. removing it from the exclude list solve the problem

Answer (score 18):

`$ find / -name "yum.conf"`

$ nano /etc/yum.conf

Remove httpd* from this line:

`exclude=apache* bind-chroot courier* dovecot* exim* filesystem httpd* mod_ssl* mydns* mysql* nsd* perl* php* proftpd* pure-ftpd* ruby* spamassassin* squirrelmail*`

Save and close yum.conf, install mod_dav_svn

`yum install mod_dav_svn`

Answer (score 0):

I use these subversion binaries for CentOS5 though I have not specifically used the mod_dav_svn RPM - [Summersoft](http://the.earth.li/pub/subversion/summersoft.fay.ar.us/pub/subversion/latest/rhel-5/i386/)

I also note that with the subversion rpms provided with CentOS 5 httpd-mmn is provided by installing httpd. Maybe you have issues with your yum configuration?

Comment: sorry if i am beiing a noob, but i dont see how this would help since curently yum can download mod_dav_svn but it gives a missing dependency 
therefore i think its more of a problem with apache then with mod_dav_svn

Comment: These RPMs are build for CentOS 5 so you should not need to recompile anything. However, I looked at the standard svn rpms that come with CentOS 5 and have updated my answer. You should not have any dependency issues if you are only using CentOS supplied RPMS. CentOS 5 comes with httpd 2.2