# Setting Subversion on the Centos Linux server

Tags: linux, svn, centos6

I am trying to setup the subversion control on the linux server, but unable to do so .
      Below are the commands I am using to install and enable the subversion , but everytime it is failing because of some dependencies . I am getting the below error when running the above command :

```
         # yum install mod_dav_svn subversion

        Error: Package: mod_dav_svn-1.6.11-9.el6_4.x86_64 (base)
        Requires: httpd-mmn = 20051115
        You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem   

  Please help me how could i resolve the above dependencies .
```

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610115/centos-install-mod-dav-svn

Answer (score 0):

http://ostechnix.wordpress.com/2013/04/30/install-subversion-server-in-centos-6-4-rhel-6-4-scientific-linux-6-4/

See the above link it would be surely easy and helpful.

Thanks & Regards,
Alok Thaker